# How to print an option's value to standard output?

Tags: vimscript, echo

I'd like to know if a file uses LF or CRLF line endings. I'm on Windows with vim installed. I don't want to convert the files, just know which line endings they use.

I know I can get the file format (`dos` or `unix`) used by running `:set ff?`, but I can't find a way to have the result printed on standard output. `:print` seems to only print a range of lines, and `:echo` doesn't print anything on stdout.

I tried using scripted ex mode:

```
vim -e -s myfile < ../script.vim
```

with `script.vim` containing:

```
echo ff?
1p
quit
```

The output contains the first line of `myfile`, so the `1p` command is executed, but I can't see the result from `echo ff?`. What's the right command to output something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `echo` with `set` in your script, and your command works fine.

See [`:help -s-ex`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#-s-ex):

> The output of these commands is displayed (to stdout):
>                           :print
>                           :list
>                           :number
>                           **:set         to display option values.**

(Emphasis mine.)

N.B. The following command also works*, and doesn't require the extra `script.vim` file:

```
vim -e -s -c "set ff?" -c "quit" myfile
```

For outputting the results of other commands to `stdout`, you may want to look into the [`:redir`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#:redir) command, e.g.

```
vim -es -c 'redir >> /dev/stdout' -c 'smile' -c 'q'
```

However, note that getting this working in the `cmd.exe` Windows Command Prompt will probably require writing the output into the buffer first and then outputting it via `:print`.

Finally, I'm pretty sure you're already aware of this, but noting for future readers that the `fileformat` option doesn't necessarily tell you what line endings the file *has*, only how Vim is interpreting it: the value depends on your `fileformats` setting.

<sub>* I'd actually write it like this: `vim -es -c "set fileformat | q" myfile`</sub>

Comment: This is strange, `set ff?` is the first thing I tried, but a that time I had tried it with the syntax `vim -s ../script.vim myfile`, and in that mode `:set ff?` doesn't work as intended.

Comment: One of my constraints is to have it run with vim on Windows. This works: `vim -e -s -c "set ff?" -c "quit" myfile`, i.e one must use double quotes. I couldn't get `vim -e -s myfile < script.vim` to work.

Comment: @liberforce That's because writing the output of `set` commands to `stdout` is specifically a feature of silent mode. Reading from a script `:h -s` is an entirely different mode of operation, which does not have that feature.

Comment: @liberforce There's several different environments you can run Vim in on Windows. Are you running in the standard Windows Command Prompt `cmd.exe`? Is that what you were using when you wrote your question? I can't get your original command to work at all in `cmd.exe`, but if it's printing out output from `1p`, I'd be surprised if it doesn't print out the output of `:set`. Might be worth reporting to the Vim developers if that's the case.

Comment: Yeah, I tried running both on Linux + `bash` (vim 7.4) and Windows + `cmd.exe` (vim 8.0). `vim -e -s myfile < script.vim` works on Linux but freezes on Windows. But the `1p` was tested on Linux, on Windows I just can't get reading the script from stdin to work, so there may be something I'm doing wrong.